# select2 with ajax even not sending request

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

no request to /example is sent when seen in firebug.
and select2 is not activated.

HTML

```
<select id="e1"  style="width: 300px" >
</select>
```

Java Script

```
$("#e1").select2(
         {   placeholder: "Select a State",
                blurOnChange: true,
                openOnEnter: false,
               ajax: {
                    url: "/example",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            method: "GetClientsByName",
                            name: term
                        };
                        }
               },
              results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                }

         }
    );
```

Comment: What have you tried to diagnose and/or debug this?  StackOverflow questions need enough detail to be answerable.

Comment: Before the $("#el1") could you log what el1 is? console.log($("#el1")? Please do it in Firefox with firebug plugin or in Chrome. You can press F12 to open the devtools window and check the console. Make sure it's not an empty jQuery object

Comment: I used firebug console. there is no request to /example

Comment: Try making a simple example work, with at least one option in the `<SELECT>` and just calling the `select2()` without any custom callbacks or options.  Make sure you do it in $(document).load(), too. That will reveal whether you've got the library loaded properly & can find the element.. which are both likely bugs.

Comment: It is working perfectly on static select list. but when I add ajax it is not.

Comment: and no java script error found in browse console.